# cancel Send mail using smtp SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, gmail

In my application, I'm using `SmtpClient` for sending emails(*only from gmail accounts*). everything is fine and perfect.

I Saw an option in gmail that allows us to cancel/undo the send mail. as shown in the below image.Here my question is regarding that, how can i cancel/undo the send mail from my program based on some conditions.

[image]

following is the code i'am using for sending mail:

```
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("frommail@company.net", "mail@gmail.com");
   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
   client.Port = 587;
   client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("frommail@company.net", "xxxxxxx");
   client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   client.EnableSsl = true;
   mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
   mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
   client.Send(mail);
   // this is what i want to do
   if(someCondition=true)
    {//undo the send operation}
```

Comment: This isn't a feature of SMTP. Just get your program to schedule sending the email in 30seconds time instead of immediately.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited knowledge, you cannot cancel a mail that was sent to a mail server. You can accomplish the undo functionality by:

- Save the mail details in a table (lets call it pending_emails) on your server
- A (delayed job is scheduled) or (recurring job runs every X minutes) and queries pending_emails for entries made 5 minutes earlier and sends them to the smtp server (as you are doing now)
- The job sends the email and deletes the email from pending_emails
- The undo button deletes the email from pending_emails

Answer (score -1):

Google just delays the send of the email by 30 seconds, easiest way to do it yourself is an async timer of 30 seconds before sending it via smtp or using a filter before sending.